Get the overlap matrix of the perturbation-dependent atomic orbitals
Is there any QC program which in calculation of NMR, magnetizabilities or other magnetic response properties at DFT level allows to print overlap matrix of the perturbation-dependent atomic orbitals S(B)? I found that Dalton, Psi4, and PySCF can print the first order overlap matrix dS(B) / dB, the first order Fock matrix dF(B) / dB, and the response vectors U(B) = dC(B) / dB. Can these matrices be used to compute S(B)?

I don't actually know, but naively, I think that either you work in a linear approximation and can get there by simple math with what you mentioned or you would need "infinitely" many terms for a Taylor-style series.
